# Unable to turn off display errors no matter what I do

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling

I've tried adding the following to the top of my `index.php` file:

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

I've also tried adding the following in to my `.htaccess` file:

```
php_flag display_errors off
```

And I've also tried creating a `php.ini` file with the following:

```
display_errors = off
```

But I'm now completely stumped, none of these will stop errors from being displayed.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with Webmin and PHP 5.4.45.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Strict standards errors, I'm using Concrete5.

Comment: Most likely one of the included scripts turns error reporting on again.